# Java ArrayList - 8x8 gameboard

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to represent an 8x8 board via a List of ArrayLists using collections. When I run this, the print statements show that the correct coordinates are being called.

```
static List<ArrayList<Integer>> BOARD = new ArrayList<>();

static {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            BOARD.add(i, new ArrayList<>());
            System.out.println("i "+i + " j "+j);
            BOARD.get(i).add(i);
            BOARD.get(i).add(j);
        }
        System.out.println("break");
        System.out.println();
    }
}

"First Iteration"
i 0 j 0
i 0 j 1
i 0 j 2
i 0 j 3
i 0 j 4
i 0 j 5
i 0 j 6
i 0 j 7
break
```

However, it does not actually put the correct elements in the lists and so it returns this:

```
[[0, 7], [1, 7], [2, 7], [3, 7], [4, 7], [5, 7], [6, 7], [7, 7], [7, 6], [7, 5], [7, 4], [7, 3], [7, 2], [7, 1], [7, 0], [6, 6], [6, 5], [6, 4], [6, 3], [6, 2], [6, 1], [6, 0], [5, 6], [5, 5], [5, 4], [5, 3], [5, 2], [5, 1], [5, 0], [4, 6], [4, 5], [4, 4], [4, 3], [4, 2], [4, 1], [4, 0], [3, 6], [3, 5], [3, 4], [3, 3], [3, 2], [3, 1], [3, 0], [2, 6], [2, 5], [2, 4], [2, 3], [2, 2], [2, 1], [2, 0], [1, 6], [1, 5], [1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 2], [1, 1], [1, 0], [0, 6], [0, 5], [0, 4], [0, 3], [0, 2], [0, 1], [0, 0]]
```

I am clearly missing something here, Ive been coding for a few hours now and can't seem to see the bug. Is this a characteristic of Collections? I thought only Queues would behave like this; but again I am not entirely sure.

Comment: Why? Much simpler to use a 2D array.

Comment: I am trying to implement this using Collections, so that I can improve my ability and familiarity with ArrayLists, Sets and Lists. However, at this point I would just rather solve it. How do you suggest I implement it?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**
I have added the `new ArrayList<>()` creation to the first loop so that for each index of the outer list there is a list

Try below code and check:

```
static List<ArrayList<Integer>> BOARD = new ArrayList<>();

static {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
       BOARD.add(i, new ArrayList<>());
       for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            System.out.println("i "+i + " j "+j);
            BOARD.get(i).add(i);
            BOARD.get(i).add(j);
        }
        System.out.println("break");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**EDIT-2:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
                integers.add(i);
                integers.add(j);
                BOARD.add(integers);
            }
            System.out.println("break");
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I am trying to create a list of 64 lists each containing 2 elements, counting incrementally e.g. [[0,0],[0,1]...[7,7]]. Or rather a solution to this problem that doesn't require such a roundabout way of using lists.

Comment: @Ventti I have edited my answer please check if it fulfills your requirement. Check EDIT-2

Comment: okay yep, so its better practice to initialise the ArrayList first? This is the correct implementation I believe. I appreciate your time and upvotes brother!!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you create in every iteration for `j` a new `ArrayList` and that replaces the old one. Move it to the upper loop and it will work. Try this:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    BOARD.add(i, new ArrayList<>());
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        System.out.println("i " + i + " j " + j);
        BOARD.get(i).add(i);
        BOARD.get(i).add(j);
    }
    System.out.println("break");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output first iteration:

> i 0 j 0
>
> i 0 j 1
>
> i 0 j 2
>
> i 0 j 3
>
> i 0 j 4
>
> i 0 j 5
>
> i 0 j 6
>
> i 0 j 7
>
> break

---

*Updated requirements*

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        final ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>();
        array.add(i);
        array.add(j);
        BOARD.add(array);
        System.out.println("i " + i + " j " + j);
    }
    System.out.println("break");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Resulting array:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [0, 5], [0, 6], [0, 7], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [1, 7], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7], [3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [3, 7], [4, 0], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4], [4, 5], [4, 6], [4, 7], [5, 0], [5, 1], [5, 2], [5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5], [5, 6], [5, 7], [6, 0], [6, 1], [6, 2], [6, 3], [6, 4], [6, 5], [6, 6], [6, 7], [7, 0], [7, 1], [7, 2], [7, 3], [7, 4], [7, 5], [7, 6], [7, 7]]
```

Comment: This implementation only returns 8 lists, of 16 elements. I am after the implementation that returns a list of 64 lists  each containing 2 elements, counting incrementally e.g. [[0,0],[0,1]...[7,7]]

Comment: @Ventti I mean one quick solution would be instead of using `BOARD.add(index, new ArrayList<>());` to create the `List` add the elements to it and after that just do `BOARD.add(createdList);` I've updated my answer

Comment: This is the correct implementation I believe. I appreciate your time and upvotes brother!!